# Controller opens file in the browser instead of downloading it

Tags: java, spring, http

I have created a controller to download a file, it works fine for small files but for bigger ones instead of downloading, it just opens the file in the browser(2kB file was downloaded but 12kB opened). I am aware of different options for downloading a file from controller but I would like to know what is the root cause of problem in my code.

My Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/logs/getfile")
    public void getFile(@RequestParam String logFile,HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {           
            String directory = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\";          
            InputStream is=new FileInputStream(new File(directory+logFile));
            IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+logFile);
            response.flushBuffer();
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `response.flushBuffer();` has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid content type. To send binary data which browser have to consider as file(binary) you have to use `application/octet-stream`

Check [list of media-types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) for complete list of valid content types for HTTP protocol

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't fix the issue nor explain the reason.

Comment: @wisnix I tried to run your code without any changes and it works for me. File is downloaded. I think it can be related to browser configuration. Are you using Chrome? Please check these 2  posts https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-reset-auto-open-settings-for-downloaded-files-in-chrome/ and https://www.presentermedia.com/blog/2013/10/my-file-automatically-opens-instead-of-saving-with-chrome/ . Can you try to use other browser?

Comment: it does the same thing in Firefox, Edge, Eclipse and Chrome so I don't think it is a browser issue.